# Insert with the current date and time

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.PROJECT(ID, LIBELLE, DESCRIPTION, STATUT, DATE_CREATION, DATE_MODIFICATION, USER_CREATEUR_ID, REFERENT_ID, DATE_DEBUT, DATE_FIN, TYPE, STATUT_PROJET) VALUES
(2651, 'Projet 1', NULL, 'START', DATE '2019-11-15', DATE '2019-11-15', NULL, 952, TIMESTAMP '2019-11-14 23:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2019-12-14 23:00:00', NULL, NULL);
```

I want to modify this request and use `current_timestamp` to have the current date and the current date with time

***Example***:  `2019-11-19 23:00:00`

I try to do that : `date (current_timestamp + time '23:00')` but i have some errors.

Someone have idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `current_date` instead:

```
current_date + time '23:00'
```

And you don't need to cast the result, use it as written.

Comment: The use `current_date - 2`

Comment: `current_date - interval '2 days'` would also work and is slightly clearer to read

Comment: @Lucas: but that returns a `timestamp` not a `date`

Comment: fair point, casting to a date as well would look a bit messy `(current_date - interval '2 days')::date`